# My Ubuntu 18.04 has dpkg gdm3 error

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

Every time I try to use command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

on my Ubuntu 18.04, it pops out the error like this:

```
Will not try to make an initrd.
Setting up linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.15.0.32.34) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.32.34) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.15.0.32.34) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35)     ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
Found Windows Boot Manager on     /dev/sdb1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea why, could anyone help me?
I also tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer     required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up gdm3 (3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned     error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


$ sudo dpkg --configure gdm3
[sudo] password for kail: 
Setting up gdm3 (3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
```

Comment: It is better to modify your answer instead of commenting your question.

Comment: What output gives you `sudo dpkg --configure gdm3`?

Comment: I have updated the output

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It appeared after upgrading to 19.10.

Comment: Hah! Rebooting fixed the error. "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"